# How to remove dual boot and assign the space to ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS along with Linux Mint 19.3. I want to remove Mint and keep only Ubuntu.

Also, I want to assign the space of Linux Mint to Ubuntu.

How should I go with it?

Answer (score 2):

Boot from the Ubuntu Live USB.

After running `swapoff` in a terminal to disable the swap files, run [GParted](https://gparted.org/) to delete the Linux Mint partition. With GParted, you define a change, then commit the change with the green checkmark, before moving on to make the next chantge.

Then you can resize the partition for Ubuntu.

You may need to [edit GRUB](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) later to remove the entry for Linux Mint.

Comment: Got an error stating **bad usage** on using swapoff